# I was out of work for 2 months, I have a firm offer now. Does that improve my chances of getting another offer, before I join?

Tags: resume, job-search, job-offer, job-change, india

I was wondering if somehow, *subtly*, I can let recruiters know that I already have an offer (on my resume/ LinkedIn headline etc.), would it improve my chances? Because it has been my experience that recruiters are hesitant to consider applicants who are not working at the time of application. If yes, how to convey this ? I'm based out of India

Comment: If you wanted to subtly hint at having other offers, without providing any proof, what is to stop others from doing the same, but lying? One good thing to say might be something along the lines of "I don't have any other offers yet, but have been talking with several other firms".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The current offer requires me to relocate with no assistance being provided by the company. Currenty, I live in a metropolitan area, so I'd like to get a similar job nearby, if possible. If I get a new offer, I can legally reject the earlier one

Comment: @Prodnegel I understand your point, but that can be clarified to the interviewer if s/he shortlists me and initiates a call/email.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks. I have about 2 weeks to join.

Comment: Call up recruiters and tell them? You're right that they shy away from people without offers, as a general rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if somehow, subtly, I can let recruiters know that I already have an offer (on my resume/ LinkedIn headline etc.), would it improve my chances?

Well, let's assume you do find an adequate way of communicating that you already have an offer to recruiters - they could take a few approaches:

- They suspect you're lying and/or it makes you sound desperate, which doesn't really bode well in either case;
- They believe that you have an offer, but they have a job they think you'll prefer so they'll put a lot of time into trying to find a job that's a better fit;
- They believe that you have an offer, and so decide that they stand a greater chance of success working with those who don't.

You seem to be hoping the second option here would be the one they'd take, but I'd say the other two are both more likely. If you don't want the job in the first offer, just decline for the reasons that you've given here (you'd have to relocate with no expenses provided for doing so). If they then ask if you're interested in other similar work, I think then is the time to reply with "Sorry, I've already rejected an offer for another company based on the need to relocate without compensation; I would however be very interested in similar opportunities nearby."

tl;dr - It's more likely to hurt, rather than help your chances.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it gives me a lot of insight into what could be thought from the other side. I'll then need to accept the offer I have, start working, and keep applying to new positions as they come. I'll have to probably ignore the small probability case of landing up a better job just by using this offer as a leverage

Comment: -1 not really answering the question?